# Solve ordinary differential equation $y''(x) +a(x) y(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

does anyone have an idea if I can write down a general solution to the following ode:

$$y''(x)+a(x) y(x)=0$$

Mathematica just tells me that "Inverse functions are being used. Values may be lost for multivalued inverses."

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: That is not a PDE (*partial* differential equation).

Comment: you are right. I corrected it

Comment: You can try to look up Handbook of Exact Solutions for Ordinary Differential Equations

Comment: Awesome. I looked this up in the book you mentioned! The correct answer should be that if you can expand $a(x)=a_0 +xa_1+x^2a_2+...$ it can be expressed in terms of Bessel functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ODE has no general closed-form solution. When $f(x) = x$, the solutions are the Airy functions which are defined by a series solution to this equation. There are a few other particular forms for $f$ that have been studied, and so the solutions are named. But for some, for example $f = \sin$, there's not even a solution that can be written in terms of a series.